# How to run a recursive chmod that stop at FileSystem Boundaries

Tags: find, chmod

I have a directory with lots of files and inside a mounted directory.

```
var/
   log/
   nfs/ (a NFS remote directory)
   www/
```

How can I `chmod`/`chown` everyfiles inside that directory without changing `nfs` ones.

Answer (score 4):

Well my solution was to use `find` to do that:

```
find . -xdev -exec chown myuser:mygroup {} \;
```

Comment: You could make that a bit faster by doing something like: `find . -xdev -exec chown myuser:mygroup {} \+`

Comment: and I prefer combining `find` with `-exec` rather than piping it to `xargs` (check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896808/find-exec-cmd-vs-xargs ) for a bit of background...

Comment: \+ or \; here `find . -xdev -exec chown myuser:mygroup {} \;`